# Angular 4 fixture component persists in DOM during Jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, typescript, jasmine

When running Jasmine in real browser I noticed that `TestBed` fixture component isn't destroyed in DOM and persists after tests have ended:

[image]

Here's a tested component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test-app',
  template: `<div>Test</div>`,
})
class Test {}
```

And a test ([plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/85mjzTBUrtNHJxlGGPxm?p=preview)).

```
  let component;
  let fixture;
  let element;

  beforeAll(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();

    TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
      BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
    );
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [Test],
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Test);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    element = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('div')).nativeElement;

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });

  it('should compile Test', () => {
    expect(element).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Why `Test` component instance isn't removed from DOM and how this should be fixed?

Why are fixture components added to DOM at all? Can they be detached from DOM like `$rootElement` in AngularJS?

Answer (score 34):

Jasmine nor Angular will ever remove it automatically, maybe to help you to get more details about your test execution.

To remove it you simply use `afterEach(...)`, like:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
  comp = fixture.componentInstance;
  debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
  element = debugElement.nativeElement;
});

afterEach(() => {
  document.body.removeChild(element);
});
```

---

For none Angular users:

```
afterEach(() => {
    document.body.innerHTML = '';
});
```

> Above clears all default `<script>` tags, but that does not matter
> (because they did already run, and Karma does never refresh the browser, at least not till all tests finish).

Comment: Thanks, answers one of the questions, *how this should be fixed?* The rest of the questions are still relevant

Answer (score 10):

A more concise solution:

```
afterEach(() => {
  element.remove()
});
```

Where `element` is `fixture.debugElement.nativeElement`

Answer (score 7):

I also experienced that changes made to the `DOM` by the testcases, like that:

```
let password = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[id=password]')).nativeElement
    password.value = 'somePassword';
```

persist across other tests. I was able to resolve this by using the following `afterEach` method:

```
afterEach(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestingModule();
  });
```

Comment: And why not you didn't use   fixture.destroy(); instead of   TestBed.resetTestingModule();?

Answer (score 6):

Please take a look at the following issues:

1) first of all you are calling

```
fixture.destroy();
```

in **afterEach**, so it's called after **it** section. I.e. in **it** section fixture is still not destroyed

2) by what code do you detect that element is still present in DOM? From another point of view: why that element should be removed by jasmine/browser (what reason should make jasmine/browser)? I could suggest the following usecases:

2.1) one component is used in another one and should be created/destroyed by some change. I.e. **ngIf** or **ngSwitchCase**:

```
<parent-component>
    <child-component *ngIf="someChangeInComponent1"></child-component>
</parent-component>
```

or

```
<parent-component [ngSwitch]="type">
    <child-component *ngSwitchCase="'something'"></child-component>
</parent-component>
```

2.2) routing is changed (but it's not a subject for unit-tests AFAIK)

3) current code receives the reference to DOM element only once. Should be something like:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    ...
    element = ...
});

it('...', () => {
    ...
    fixture.detectChanges();
    element = ... // try to get element again <--------------------- here
})
```

4) if you are trying to find errors like **ngOnDestroy()** is defined but **implements OnDestroy** is not used then it's more a subject for **npm run lint** than for unit tests (please take a look at **use-life-cycle-interface** in **tslint.json**). After running **npm run lint** you'll just see:

```
Implement lifecycle hook interface OnDestroy for method ngOnDestroy in class ...
```

It's a good practice to have no errors not only for unit test but for tslint too.

Comment: *by what code do you detect that element is still present in DOM* - by my own eyes. You can see this in a plunk that was posted in the question. *what reason should make jasmine/browser* - because we can. It's one of Jasmine core features. And Angular ruins the report for no obvious reason. I would like to know why it's that, considering that it was ok in AngularJS. I believe the questions in the end of the OP are specific enough.

Comment: @estus it could be some kind of regression. need more investigation. the following url could be interesting for you: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8458

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it was fixed long time ago. I think this is related to how TestBed works and likely this is how it is expected to work by default. Just not sure why, and how this can be changed if possible.